# Checking If tags has content or not

Tags: channel-entries, conditionals, ifelse

I want to check if two tags have content in them, and set html markup accordingly. 
And I reuse this snippet several places and I'm having inconsistent results.

```
{if site_hvite_left == "" OR site_hvite_right == ""}
    <div class="row-small">
{if:else}
    <div class="row">
{/if}
```

Some places this works just fine, but other places, I need to add a space in between the quotes for it to make it work. Which makes me think there might be a better way of doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: If both fields have content or one of them? Please, update your question and give us more details. Maybe, the [`:empty` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) can help you too.

Comment: If one of them has content, like the IF statement says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{if '{site_hvite_left}' == '' OR '{site_hvite_right}' == ''}
    <div class="row-small">
{if:else}
    <div class="row">
{/if}
```

.. a bit verbose but it should work every time.

Comment: Actually, it was the single quotes that made it work. But out of curiosity, what makes the '{site_hvite_left}' tag differ from 'site_hvite_left' without brackets?

Comment: Well, what makes single quotes differ from double? The EE template parser works in mysterious ways. It's a regexp search-and-replace solution, so my logic with the above is that {site_hvite_left} etc. will be replaced with content first if they have brackets. Turns out it was the quotes in this case, but the above is still what I have found to work in most cases. And btw - nobody really knows how this parser works in all situations (even EllisLab support will just tell you to try different solutions until you hit one that works).